# Estimate the bound of the sum of the roots of $1/x+\ln x=a$ where $a>1$

Tags: analysis, inequality

If $a>1$ then  $\frac{1}{x}+\ln x=a$ has two distinct roots($x_1$ and $x_2$, Assume $x_1<x_2$). Show that $$x_1+x_2+1<3\exp(a-1)$$

---

First I tried to estimate the place of the roots separately. I have got that $x_1\leq \frac{1}{a}$ and $\exp(a-1)<x_2<\exp(a)$. Then I tried to think about $x_1 + x_2$ as a whole. Because $1/x_1+\ln x_1=a$ and $1/x_2+\ln x_2=a$. I tried to express $x_1+x_2$ as a function of $a$, But I failed. I have no idea to solve this problem. Please help me  :)

Comment: This bound is very sharp when $a\to 1$... It really seems not trivial

Comment: If i did the math right, it would amount to show that: $W_0(x)+W_{-1}(x)+W_0(-x^2-\alpha x)>0$, with $\alpha = 3/e$, and $W_0,W_{-1}$ the two branches of the Lambert W function. ($x=-e^{-a}$). One could also ask what is the minimum $\alpha$ for which the sum stays positive, but I couldn't go forward on it.

Comment: PS: the original inequality reads $$\frac{1}{W_0(-e^{-a})}+\frac{1}{W_{-1}(-e^{-a})} > 1 + 3e^{a-1}$$.

Comment: I did the numerical solution to this problem (up to $ a=20$). It turns out that the bound is not at all sharp, in fact the difference between the bound and the $x_1+x_2$ increases abruptly (for $a=19$ is about $1.8\times 10^7$). It turns out that an upper bound (starting with $a>5$) that gets arbitrarily close from above to the sum of the roots is $1/a*(1-ln(a)/a)+exp(a-exp(-a))$. The difference to the sum of the roots is for $a=19$ about $8\times 10^{-4}$. @Ewan-Delanoy: can you prove this?

Answer (score 6):

The function $\frac1x+\ln x$ is decreasing in $(0,1]$ and it is increasing in $[1,\infty)$; each has the range $[1,\infty)$. So, we have two inverse functions, $x:[1,\infty)\to (0,1]$ (decreasing) and $y:[1,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$ (increasing), satisfying 
$$ \frac1{x(a)}+\ln x(a)=\frac1{y(a)}+\ln y(a)=a. \tag1$$
We want to prove $x(a)+y(a)+1<3e^{a-1}$ for $a>1$.

As $x(1)=y(1)=1$, we have $x(1)+y(1)+1=3$, so it suffices to prove $\big(\ln(x(a)+y(a)+1)\big)'<1$ for $a>1$.

By differentiating (1), we get $-\frac{x'}{x^2}+\frac{x'}{x}=1$, so
$x'=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ and similarly $y'=\frac{y^2}{y-1}$, therefore
$$
\big(\ln(x(a)+y(a)+1)\big)'
= \frac{x'+y'}{x+y+1}
= \frac{\frac{x^2}{x-1}+\frac{y^2}{y-1}}{x+y+1} =
1 + \frac{xy-1}{(x-1)(y-1)(x+y+1)}.
$$
In the denominator of the last fraction we have $x<1$, so we need $xy>1$.

By a straightforward calculation it can be verified that $t\ln (t^2)<t^2-1$ for $t>1$. Applying this with $t=\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}} \ln\frac{y}{x} < \frac{y}{x}-1 
= y \bigg(\frac1x-\frac1y\bigg) 
= y\big((a-\ln x)-(a-\ln y)\big) 
= y\big(\ln y-\ln x\big) 
= y \ln\frac{y}{x} \\
xy > 1.
$$

Comment: Beautiful work here!

Answer (score 2):

I can show the inequality when $a$ is close enough to $1$ (namely, $a\leq 1+ln(5/4)\approx 1.22$) or when $a$ is big enough (namely, $a \geq 1+\ln(5) \approx 2.6$). In the sequel $f(x)$ denotes $x+\ln(\frac{1}{x})$.

**When $a$ is close to $1$**. Let us put $w=\sqrt{e^{a-1}-1}$. The inequality then becomes $x_1+x_2\leq 2+3w^2$. Now I claim that when $w\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, one has

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_1 & \leq & 1-\sqrt{2}w+\frac{4}{3}w^2 \\
x_2 & \leq & 1+\sqrt{2}w+\frac{5}{3}w^2 \\
\end{array}
$$

To check the first claim, let $g(w)=f(1-\sqrt{2}w+\frac{4}{3}w^2)-1-\ln(1+w^2)$. Then the derivative of $g$ is $g'(w)=\frac{w^3(\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2}w-\frac{34}{9})}{(1+w^2)(1-\sqrt{2}w+\frac{4}{3}w^2)^2}<0$. So $g$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, whence $g(w)\leq g(0)=0$, proving the first claim.

To check the second claim, let $h(w)=f(1+\sqrt{2}w+\frac{5}{3}w^2)-1-\ln(1+w^2)$. Then the derivative of $h$ is $h'(w)=\frac{w^2(\frac{-5}{3}\sqrt{2}w^2-\frac{28}{9}w+sqrt(2)))}{(1+w^2)(1+\sqrt{2}w+\frac{5}{3}w^2)^2}$. So $h'$ has a unique zero in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ ; since $h(0)=0$ and $h(\frac{1}{2})\approx 0.00091 >0$, we have $h(w)\geq 0$ for any $w\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$, proving the second claim.

**When $a$ is big enough**. Let us put $u=e^{a-1}$. The inequality then becomes $x_1+x_2+1\leq 3u$. Now I claim that when $u\geq 5$, one has

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_1 & \leq & (3-e)u-1 \\
x_2 & \leq & eu \\
\end{array}
$$

To check the first claim, let $k(u)=f((3-e)u-1)-1-ln(u)$. Then the derivative of $k$ is $k'(w)=\frac{-1} {u((3-e)u-1)^2}<0$. So $k$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, and since $k(5)\approx -1.05 <0$, this proves the first claim.

The second claim follows from the identity $f(eu)-1-ln(u)=\frac{1}{eu}$.

Comment: how about this bound that gets arbitrarily close from above to the sum of the roots, for all $a>5$: $$\frac{1}{a}\left(1-\frac{ln a}{a}\right)+\exp(a-\exp(-a))?$$ (see my comment above).

Comment: @Chip You should ask this as a separate question